# É possível importar variáveis ​​em JavaScript (Node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Tenho variáveis ​​em `app.js`:

```
var G = {};
module.exports = G;

var DATA = G.DATA = 'DATA';
var F1 = G.F1　= function(val)
{
  return val;
};
```

Desta forma, posso exportar variáveis ​​sob o objeto `G`, e, ao mesmo tempo, pode aceder a variável escrever diretamente `DATA` sem `G`. prefixo.

Agora, eu quero fazer um teste para `app.js` em *`test.js`*

```
var G = require('./app.js');
console.log(G.DATA);  // -> DATA
```

Isso funciona, mas eu também quero acessar a variável escrevendo diretamente `DATA` sem `G`. Prefixo como `console.log(DATA); // -> DATA`

Certamente, eu poderia fazer como:

```
var DATA = G.DATA;
```

Para cada variáveis ​​(propriedade) de exportação e necessário módulo `G` objeto, mas, obviamente, é um processo tedioso para adicionar cada variável para o arquivo de teste manualmente para corresponder a `G` objeto.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso automaticamente?

Até agora, eu sou pessimista desde

JS `function` encerra `var` no próprio âmbito, então, em teoria, não há nenhuma maneira de ter uma função auxiliar para `var` para cada objeto de propriedade.

Eu gostaria de evitar qualquer `eval` ou `VM` de solução nó. Eu tentei-los no passado, e teve demais problemas.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar `with`:

```
with (G) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

O `with` não é muito usado, nem recomendado usar, pois coloca todas as propriedades do objeto que você estiver especificando como se fossem globais, o que gera erros e atrapalha encontrar os.

Lembrando ainda, que pelo motivo acima o uso de `with` não é permitido no modo restrito (`'use strict'`), embora seja permitido no Node.js. Logo tirando por esses problemas o uso dele funcionará no seu caso.

Comment: De realçar mesmo que o `with` pode causar bugs e tem um efeito negativo no desempenho do programa.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que você queira fazer isso:

file.js

```
module.exports = {
   DATA: "MY DATA"
}
```

app.js

```
var f = require('file.js');
console.log(f.DATA); // MY DATA
```

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia utilizar um módulo que já vem no core do Node.JS chamado [vm](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html).

Por exemplo:

```
var vm = require('vm');
var fs = require('fs');

var testFile = fs.readFileSync('./test.js');
var app = require('./app.js');

var local = {};
var ctx = vm.createContext(local);

// Essa função vai executar o código do `test.js`
// e todo parâmetro do objeto `local` será utilizado
// como contexto (variáveis locais)
vm.runInContext(testFile,ctx);

// Você poderá acessar o contexto manipulado
console.log(ctx);
```

Comment: Interessante sua resposta, porém ele especificou que não queria usar VM. :)

Comment: Não vi esse detalhe. Mas de qualquer forma fica a dica.
Eu utilizo VM em várias soluções minhas e dificilmente encontro algum problema.
Normalmente problemas com VM você encontra quando precisa fazer algum isolamento.